# Producing html for Chinese documents with Tex4Ht

Tags: cjk, tex4ht

I'm using TexLive 2011 on Ubuntu 11.10. Take this for example:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
文章内容。
\end{document}
```

Then I run `htlatex test.tex` to convert it to html, but after conversion, the Chinese characters are not displayed in the browser. Then I checked the html source, it's like this:

```
<body>
<!--l. 3--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="unisong-65x-x-105"></span><span 
class="unisong7a-x-x-105"></span><span 
class="unisong-51x-x-105"></span><span 
class="unisong5b-x-x-105"></span><span 
class="unisong-30x-x-105"></span>
</body>
```

Seems like it's converting the characters in the weirdest way.

So how do I configure it to let it produce readable Chinese? If tex4ht isn't able to do this, what other tools should I look into?

Comment: It is mainly because of the wrongly produced .htf files. (htf 文件没做好，以前是不同人做的，不匹配。这是已知的问题，ctex-kit 上很早的 issue 了，不过都觉得应用很少没人处理。)

Comment: You can find more information at http://code.google.com/p/ctex-kit/issues/detail?id=46

Comment: @LeoLiu I'm translating a [book](https://gitorious.org/learn-c-the-hard-way) written in Latex. It uses tex4ht to produce an HTML version. Guess it leaves me no choice :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because `tex4ht` can't find the `htf` font files, i.e. `unisong51.htf` etc. However, `tex4ht` *does* come with `utf8song*.htf` files in `%TEX4HT%/ht-fonts/unicode/cjk/utf8/`, so you could just create copies of those. (`%TEX4HT%` is likely to be `%TEXMF%/tex4ht` on your system.)

Here's what I did.

- Create a copy of each `utf8song*.htf` to `unisong*.htf`, and modify the *first* and *last* lines of the file contents to `unisong*` accordingly.
- In my case, I had to also edit `%TEX4HT%/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env`. (Or in `win32` if you're on Windows). Change all the `~/tex4ht.dir/texmf` in that file to the actual path where my `TEXMF` tree really is, especially the ones under the heading `<unihtf>`.
- Then run the following command:

  `htlatex test.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8,NoFonts" " -cunihtf -utf8"`

I was then able to get a readable webpage in Chinese.

Comment: Personally I don't think tex4ht is a proper tool to produce HTML pages. `pandoc` is a better choice, I think.

Comment: @LeoLiu +1 for `pandoc`, I use it for writing my "first drafts". But IMHO `tex4ht` wins hands-down on most "real-life" LaTeX documents. `pandoc` can't handle beyond a few common LaTeX packages, while `tex4ht` can almost handle any packages you throw at it. So it really depends on how complicated your LaTeX document is, especially w.r.t. the kinds of macros and packages you're using.

Comment: @Lim: Well, I would just use markdown for `pandoc` to produce both HTML and PDF (via LaTeX).

Comment: @LianTzeLim I think this only solves font issues for simsun or 新宋体. How do I make it work for all Chinese fonts, like simhei, simkai, and those Wenquanyi fonts?

Comment: I tried to find a way to direct tex4ht to just look at utf8song* for all CJK, since the metrics and encodings should be the same anyway (as long as we're still talking about UTF8), but I haven't found it yet (assuming it does exist). If you need a solution urgently, the best bet might be to write a script to create copies of appropriately renamed `utf8song*.htf` files, by looking at the errors you'll know what to rename them to. Really ugly and dirty, I know, so hopefully I (or someone else!) will be able to find the correct parameter soon. >_<

Comment: Bejing lazy, anyone would like to upload one archive containing the modified files to google drives or sw else? :)

Comment: Also, i did not find any string like `~/tex4ht.dir/texmf` in that file