# .htf for Chinese utf8 fonts other than unisong*

Tags: fonts, texlive, cjk, tex4ht

In continue with this question: [Producing html for Chinese documents with Tex4Ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48110/producing-html-for-chinese-documents-with-tex4ht)

Tex4Ht requires .htf fonts for converting Chinese documents. I've managed to make all the `unisong*.htf` fonts work thanks to the answer to the previous question, but the default TexLive 2011 installation doesn't seem to contain htf fonts for simhei, simkai, and all other Chinese fonts. Is there a place where I can download them, or how do I generate them if I can?

Comment: There are `.htf` files for GBK encoding installed in TeX Live. So you can change the document encoding to use GBK font mappings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found the `alias` htf files, which makes the business of reusing the `utf8song*.htf` files (contributed by CTeX forumers, now shipped  with `tex4ht`) easier.

After an initial (unsuccessful) run of `tex4ht`, you'd notice the errors messages like

`--- warning --- Couldn't find font 'unihei7a.htf' (char codes: 0--255)`

So you know you will need to map `unihei*.htf` files to use `utf8song*.htf` instead.

For each `utf8song*.htf` file in `%TEX4HT%/ht-fonts/unicode/cjk/utf8/`, create a file `unihei*.htf` that contains the single line
`.utf8song*` .

The following Bash script will generate new alias `unihei*.htf` files from `utf8song*.htf`:

`for file in *.htf; do alias_name=${file/utf8song/unihei}; sudo echo .${file%.htf} > $alias_name; done;`

You can leave the new files in `%TEX4HT%/ht-fonts/unicode/cjk/utf8/`, or move them to `%TEX4HT%/ht-fonts/alias/cjk/utf8/` for tidier housekeeping.

(Again, remember to check that `tex4ht.dir` in `%TEX4HT%/tex4ht/base/unix/tex4ht.env` is replaced with the correct actual path.)

Then run

`htlatex test.tex "xhtml,charset=utf-8,NoFonts,fonts" " -cunihtf -utf8"`

(The `NoFonts` directive eliminates the verbose `<span>`s around each CJK character. The `fonts` directive would put a `<span>` for things like `\textbf`, `\emph` with the appropriate classes, so that you can style them with CSS as you may wish.)

Comment: Works again! With this method I'm using utf8song all the way long, but at least the text is properly displayed. Thanks!

Comment: @WangDingwei Even for English, by default all the text will be displayed in Times New Roman (or whatever the browser's default font is) `:)`. You could still use CSS to style the fonts, e.g. `.sectionHead, .textbf {font-family:黑体;} .emph {font-family:楷体;}` . Note that you need to have the `fonts` directive when running `htlatex` to get the `textbf`, `emph` etc class names. (I've updated my answer accordingly.)

Answer (score 1):

To produce `.htf` files for Chinese UTF-8 fonts, you can use the script described in [CTeX forum](http://bbs.ctex.org/viewthread.php?tid=44057).

BTW, why not search or ask the question in Chinese forums?

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did see that post from the CTex BBS, but seeing it come from almost 4 years ago, I wonder if there's anything new to it. I will try ask in the CTex forum if I have more questions :)